# How do I override empty rule with messages in JOI 17?

Tags: javascript, joi

I read [Node.js + Joi how to display a custom error messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48720942/node-js-joi-how-to-display-a-custom-error-messages) and am still having trouble.

I have a schema like this:

```js
const create = validator.object().keys({
  app: validator
    .string()
    .required()
    .valid(...ARRAY_OF_VALUES)
    .messages({'any.unknown':'Must pass valid code'})
});
```

An update of the question above points at https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#list-of-errors for the valid error types.

I test with a value of `invalid!` and still see the default error message. I have tried `string.unknown`, `string.invalid`, `any.invalid` to no avail.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63632575/1499476, using this answer, you can try finding out what error is being thrown. Then overriding it using .messages().

Comment: You can use `any.only`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a custom error message regardless of error type, you can use '*' instead of 'any.unknown' as follows:

```
const create = validator.object().keys({
  app: validator
    .string()
    .required()
    .valid(...ARRAY_OF_VALUES)
    .messages({'*':'Must pass valid code'})
});
```

For more information, check the description for the messages function here: https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.6.0#anyvalidatevalue-options

Answer (score 0):

Use `string.empty`

```
const create = validator.object().keys({
  app: validator
   .string()
   .required()
   .valid(...ARRAY_OF_VALUES)
   .messages({'string.empty':'Must pass valid code'})
});
```